React Cache Issue
I have a React website created with create-react-app where I upload blogs. When a user visits my website and then opens a blog link from a social networking site (e.g., Facebook, Twitter), they sometimes get a 404 Page Not Found error. This happens because the previously cached version of the website is loaded from the browser. How can I prevent this issue and ensure that users can access the blog links even after previously visiting the website?
I have implemented react-cache-buster in my app:
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CacheBuster } from 'react-cache-buster';
import Loading from './Loading'; // Import your Loading component
import error404 from './error404'; // Import your 404 error component

function App() {
  return (
    <CacheBuster
      currentVersion={version}
      isEnabled={true}
      isVerboseMode={false}
      loadingComponent={<Loading />}
      metaFileDirectory={'./'}
    >
      <BrowserRouter basename={'/'}>
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/health-care`} component={HeathCare} />
            <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/healthtech`} component={HealthTech} />
            <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/fintech`} component={Fintech} />
            <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/logistics`} component={Logistics} />
            <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/ecommerce`} component={eCommerce} />
            <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/*`} component={error404} />
          </Switch>
        </React.Suspense>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </CacheBuster>
  );
}

export default App;

